# Retrofit, Response code es 200, pero response.body() es null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Me pueden ayudar con este problema, tengo la pantalla de inicio de sesión, cuando ejecuto la aplicación desde Android Studio, funciona bien y pasa a la siguiente actividad. Sin embargo, cuando genero el apk me muestra el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Solo cuando genero el apk response.body() es nulo.

code

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Object Retrofit

```
object GetRetrofit {
  fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
     val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()

    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Cadena_g.url_serv)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si él response code es 200, indica que la petición se realizó con éxito, el cliente ha solicitado la información al servidor y el servidor respondió al cliente y le entregó la información. Si la respuesta tiene un valor null, esta es la respuesta con base en la información que enviaste al servidor.

Puedes iniciar por revisar si tu API no esta restringida su uso para tu aplicación o si las credenciales son las adecuadas para consumir la API.

---

Actualización:

El OP refiere que se solucionó deshabilitando `minifyEnabled` :

```
minifyEnabled false
```

`minifyEnabled true`, elimina código no utilizado, esto provoca en [algunos casos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205842/retrofit-null-response-after-publishing-app/70850919#70850919) que algunas aplicaciones fallen debido a una excepción `NoSuchFieldException`

Comment: Muchas gracias por su aporte estimado, el problema es el siguiente: si yo compilo de android studio response.body() me devuelve todos los datos, por otra parte, si genero el apk me devuelve nulo.

Comment: Probablemente tu API esta restringida, agrega información sobre la petición y que API usas para obtener los datos, que valores envías?

Comment: Que tal @Jorgesys resolví mi problema mediante este comentario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850919/19859234, de este modo, se modifico el build.gradle cambiando de minifyEnabled true a minifyEnabled false. De ante mano, muchas gracias por sus respuesta!!.

Comment: minifyEnabled=true se usa para reducir, ofuscar y optimizar la app, por experiencia se que puede afectar el funcionamiento de ciertas clases, pero es raro, veo que esa respuesta nadie le ha dado ni un voto. Solo dime por favor que bibliotecas estas usando en tu app para tomarlo en cuenta.

Comment: a que Biblioteca te referís????

Comment: Lee mi actualización, me parece que en tu caso sucedió que hay código que lo eliminaba, por eso se provocaba el error

Comment: Veo que se usa Retrofit como librería HTTP, justo en su documentación mencionan los paquetes y clases que se deben de agregar al proguard-rules.pro para evitar este tipo de errores usando minify https://square.github.io/retrofit/